# problems installing M2Crypto on Mint

Tags: python, gcc, swig, m2crypto, linux-mint

I am trying to install M2Crypto for python on Mint 12.  I have executed `python setup.py build, but the build fails, stating

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

the preceding 2 lines show that there may be a problem with Python.h:

```
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:126:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

If anyone knows what needs to be done to fix this, please let me know.

**EDIT**

I have attempted to install `python-dev`, but I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev: Depends: python (= 2.6.6-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.2-7ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that you miss the python-dev package which contains `python.h`

Comment: I attempted to install python-dev, but got an error stating I have broken packages. I will post the error in an update above.

Comment: @ewok : try an `apt-get install -f` to repair your installation

Answer (score 1):

try following command

> $sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto

Answer (score 0):

Compiling on recent Debian, Ubuntu or derivatives like Mint gives an error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

Corresponding question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553118/problems-installing-m2crypto-on-mint-follow-up/14835020).