# problems installing M2Crypto on Mint: follow-up

Tags: python, linux, ssl, m2crypto, linux-mint

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539676/problems-installing-m2crypto-on-mint) regarding installing the M2Crypto python library in Mint.  That question was answered successfully and I was able to build and install M2Crypto.  However, I am not able to use it within Python.  when I attempt to import the module, I get the following error:

```
>>> import M2Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import __m2crypto
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

If anyone know how to resolve this error, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug introduced in M2Crypto 0.21.1, there is a [patch here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-637904-m2crypto-so-undefined-symbol-sslv2-method-help-204454061.html) that correct the problem.

Maybe you could try to install an old version of M2Crypto (like the 0.20.1-1.1) or apply the patch manually with the [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) command.

Comment: can you explain how to install that patch?  there doesn't seem to be an explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 16):

After two years the problem in m2crypto0.21.1 still exists, so here is a note for Ubuntu users. If you're not using `virtualenv`, you can easily fix it by installing m2crypto from Ubuntu PPA instead of pip:

```
sudo pip uninstall m2crypto 
sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto
```

Seems like the problem is fixed in the PPA, but not in the project's repo. At least it worked for me at Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

To expand the answer above:

This is a bug in M2Crypto 0.21.1. It has to do with the fact that SSLv2 was removed from OpenSSL on many platforms on the grounds of it being too insecure, notably Debian [[1](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=589706)] and Ubuntu.

The removal is not detected during compile. There is a widely available patch that fixes this. I incorporated this into the M2Crypto source code on Github.

You can use pip to install directly from the repository like so:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/Hypernode/m2crypto#egg=M2Crypto
```

For those who want to inspect the (much published) patch that fixes this: [b432d36](https://github.com/Hypernode/M2Crypto/commit/b432d362223b2e2f5565dfb2eea799d10a419e22)

Edit: moved to another location